# How to add another table column in searchable array in nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, searchable

i am getting data from different different tables and i displayed all those in one section that section contains search button also, i want to add another resource field as a searchable item in nova ,i am trying to add based on the relation of the particular table but it's throwing an error undefined column, How to add please help..

```
public static $searchable=['id','name','account.type'];
```

Comment: you can check out [this](https://github.com/TitasGailius/nova-search-relations) package.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the search by relationship is not possible through Nova.

---

A package well made for your needs is this one: [LaravelNovaSearch](https://github.com/akki-io/laravel-nova-search)

This package includes both relationship search but also has other useful features making the search much more comprehensive.

---

Another package, which I have not personally tested, but which seems to be useful for your needs: [NovaSearchRelations](https://github.com/TitasGailius/nova-search-relations)

---

**My advice is to use LaravelNovaSearch, more maintained and more complete.**